# Spring Boot REST service – End User Authentication vs APP (REST client) Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

I have gone through many posts and articles but didn't find a straightforward solution for the case below which I have to implement.

**Platform:**  Spring Boot 2.x.x (Spring Security 5.x.x) with embed Tomcat

**Solution:** REST service that consume many client apps and many end users.

1. I have to implement a REST end point `/api/search` which accessible for many client application. As an example, web application APP-X (Angular), web application APP-Y(Jquery/Bootstrap) and mobile application APP-Z (IOS). All three clients are separate entities (both technical perspective and business perspective).
2. So I have to authenticate above application using onetime token. Therefore I planned to go for Spring OAuth2 by enabling `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and `@EnableResourceServer`. For each app client I’ll generate a token and they can use it when they connect with my REST service. **Is this approach correct?**
3. Apart from the app clients system has capability to register and login functionality for end users. Also my end point (`/api/search`) can access both anonymous users and users who registered under `ROLE_REGUSER` role. And through the security context, I need to access the user details as usual user authentication.
4. This is the place I got stuck. How can I handle the following points together using Spring Security 5.x.x (Spring Boot 2.x.x).

> I. Both client apps and end users authentications.
>   II. Allow access for **anonymous** users and registered users for same end point.

I have attached small diagram to elaborate the above scenario.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution when I upgraded my spring security version to 5.2. 
In version 5.2, they have depreciated `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and `@EnableResourceServer`. So I had to move with an external authorization provider who supports auth2. I chose AWS Cognito, and fulfill the above requirement, using the user pool option.

[**In AWS Cognito**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-create-user-pool.html)

1. I created a user pool.
2. Then created two app clients in the same user pool.
3. One app client configured as support to the client credentials flow.
4. The second app client configured as support to the user authentication flow.

[**In client applications**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html)

1. Retrieve access token directly from AWS Cognito using client credentials and used to secure all API calls.
2. If a user login at any stage, retrieve access token directly from AWS Cognito using the authorization code and replace any existing access token.

> *The advantage is, the resources server can validate any access token that generated related to the same user pool.*

[**In resources server (backend API/Spring Boot)**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver)

1. [Validate access token](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.2.1.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver).